# XSLT how to edit KML Placemark Style based on description value

Tags: xml, xslt, kml

I'm a XSLT newbie and I'd like to edit the following KML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="doc">
<Schema name="Geographic_Placemarks">
  <SimpleField name="Description" type="string" />
  <SimpleField name="x" type="string" />
  <SimpleField name="y" type="string" />
</Schema>
<Folder>
  <name>Geographic_Placemarks</name>

     <Placemark>
    <name>Site 1</name>
    <description>23</description>
    <Style>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <fill>0</fill>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <ExtendedData>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Geographic_Placemarks">
        <SimpleData name="x">571750    </SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="y">4548250    </SimpleData>
      </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>clampToGround    </altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround    </altitudeMode>
          <coordinates>11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511     11.1298128785963,45.7000370530753 11.1833198656477,45.6994951268141 11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511    </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>

  <Placemark>
    <name>Site 2</name>
    <description>10</description>
    <Style>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <fill>0</fill>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <ExtendedData>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Geographic_Placemarks">
        <SimpleData name="x">575750</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="y">4548250</SimpleData>
      </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
          <coordinates>11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511     11.1833198656477,45.6994951268141 11.2337967406582,45.6989609013362 11.2329870100429,45.6607994408117 11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511      </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
     </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

In particular I'd like to modify the style part of each placemark, based on the description value. if the description value is 23 i'd like to substitute the style part in this way:

```
<LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000ff</color>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
    <fill>0.5</fill>
    <color>ff0000ff</color>
</PolyStyle>
```

Otherwise in case the description value is 10 I'd like to to substitute the style part in this way:

```
<LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000ff</color>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
    <fill>1</fill>
    <color>#ffff99</color>
</PolyStyle>
```

In other words i'd like to change the KML layout based on the description value

Please can you help me in the XSL setup? Thanks in advance.

EDIT To follow your suggestions i included the xslt file, but it's not well formed. As I said I'm not so skilled in XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:for-each select="kml:Placemark">
    <xsl:variable name="Value" select="@description"/>
      <xsl:when test="$Value = '10'">
        <xsl:element name="$Style">

        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <color>#ffff99</color>
            </PolyStyle>

        </xsl:element>  
       </xsl:when>

    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? -- Also, are 23 and 10 the only possible values? If not, what should happen when the value is neither of these?

Comment: I tryed several time from the examples online to write an xslt file doing this, but I don't have the knowledge of the basic statements of the language to achieve this issue. I included that strings ('23' and '10') only for a first simple and general approach, to understant the xslt structure, but could be interesting also to understand how to evaluate in general the corresponding number converted values. So for example how to evaluate if the description value (converted in number) is between 25 and 50 . thx for the patience

Comment: Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k   ok posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a big choose/when block I recommend individual templates to replace just the pieces that need changing. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <!-- identity template copies nodes unchanged -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- matches Style with sibling of description='23' -->
    <xsl:template match="kml:Style[../kml:description='23']">
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <fill>0.5</fill>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- matches Style with sibling of description='10' -->
    <xsl:template match="kml:Style[../kml:description='10']">
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <color>#ffff99</color>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This could of course be refined further, for example if you're only actually changing PolyStyle you could write the templates to match that element.